# How to get text from a windows task manager task listview

Tags: c, taskmanager

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>

LVFINDINFO information;
POINT poss;
LVITEM lvi;

void main(void) {
    HWND father = FindWindow(NULL, "Gerenciador de Tarefas do Windows");
    HWND child = FindWindowEx(father, 0, NULL, NULL);
    HWND listview = FindWindowEx(child, 0, "SysListView32", "Processos");
    DWORD PID;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(listview, &PID);

    HANDLE process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, 
        FALSE, PID);
    lvi.cchTextMax = 512;
    LPVOID address = VirtualAllocEx(process, NULL, sizeof(LVITEM), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    lvi.iSubItem = 0;
    printf("%i\n", address);
    WriteProcessMemory(process, address, &lvi, sizeof(lvi), NULL);
    int indice = SendMessage(listview, LVM_GETITEMTEXT, 1, (LPARAM)&address);
    printf("%i\n", indice);

}
```

I'm trying to get the text from the processes listed in the task manager but unsuccessfully because when I run the task manager code it stops working. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to use `LVM_GETITEMTEXT` without target application crashing in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4616326/541686). **The answer to your question is there.**

Comment: insists on the error still, I do not know if you observed but I am trying to get items from a listview of the windows manager, the problem is not the same ]:>

Comment: the problem is you're passing `(LPARAM)&address` which is an address to a pointer in your own process, not in task manager.

Comment: and asking too much for you to come up with a friendly solution? I'm lost

Comment: Uhm, just remove the `&`...

Comment: It really worked, but the problem now and other text is not recovered.

Comment: If you still need help with a new problem, please open a new question explaining the new problem. Please also work on your English when writing the question. Initially it was understandable, but in these comments it got so much worse that at this point I cannot understand what you are saying in your latest comment. Specifically, please write in complete sentences.

Comment: OK, sorry... thank you!!